# PHP - How to create IF like function

Tags: php, function

I am trying to create a function like `if`

```
if(arguments){
    code
}
```

So what i want to create is

```
**Define Function**
myFunction(Arguments){
    do something with arguments
    return ;
}
**call function**
myFunction(Arguments){ 
    After my function has run or what ever it is suppose to do Run the code between the blocks.
}
```

Not sure what to call it or search.

Comment: Can you share more context? Why do you think that you need such a structure?

Comment: Hi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. As you are a new user I thought it might be optimal to tell you about this feature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer is: This is **not** possible

`if` is a [control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Sadly it is not possible to create own control structures without manipulating the PHP Library source code which is way out of scope for optimal use.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make it as your own structure, but you can achieve quite similar result with using normal function with anonymous function as parameter - code example below:

```
<?php

function myCustom($condition, $execution) {
    if ($condition) {
        return call_user_func($execution);
    }
    return false; // explicitly return false on $condition failure 
                  // (best practise)
                  // Or handle by your own (there could be your own logic - eg. logger or something
}

myCustom(1 == 1, function(){ echo 1;});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```php
function isArgumentAwesome($argument) {
    // determine if your function should return true || false, based on the given argument.

    // example
    return $argument === 'awesome';
}

if (isArgumentAwesome($variable_to_check)) {
    // run code when $variable_to_check === 'awesome'.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't do this with an IF statement.

An approach, you could do something similar with a class, for example:

```
class MyProcessClass {
   public $arguments;
   function __construct($argumentsArr) {
     $arguments = $argumentsArr;
     //code
   }

   function afterFunction() {
     // After code
   }
}

$process = new MyProcess($arguments);
$process->after();
```